# extracting string occurrence in c

Tags: c, strstr

I have a string that look something like this:

```
long_str = "returns between paragraphs 20102/34.23\" - 9203 1232 \"test\" \"basic HTML\"";
```

Note: Quotes are part of the string.

```
int match(char *long_str){
    char * str;
    if ((str = strchr(long_str, '"')) != NULL) str++; // last " ?
    else return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Using `strstr` I'm trying to get the whole substring between the last two quotes: `"basic HTML"`.   I'm just not quite sure what would be a good and efficient way of getting that match. I'm open to any other ideas on how to approach this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * long_str = 
"returns between paragraphs 20102/34.23\" - 9203 1232 \"test\" \"basic HTML\"";

int main ()
{
    char * probe;
    char * first_quote = 0;
    char * second_quote = 0;
    for (probe = long_str; * probe; probe++) {
        if (*probe == '"') {
            if (first_quote) {
                if (second_quote) {
                    first_quote = second_quote;
                    second_quote = probe;
                } else {
                    second_quote = probe;
                }
            } else {
                first_quote = probe;
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("%s\n", first_quote);
    printf ("%d-%d\n", first_quote - long_str, second_quote - long_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can avoid some nesting in the conditions by inverting the conditions: `if (first_quote == 0) first_quote = probe; else if (second_quote == 0) second_quote = probe; else { first_quote = second_quote; second_quote = probe; }`.  You could even use '`if (*probe != '"') continue; else if ...`, but I wouldn't normally bother.

Comment: +1 `probe`  good name for the variable considering it's use *probing* through the string

Comment: You shouldn't need a condition at all, `if (*probe == '"') { first_quote = second_quote; second_quote = probe;}` then make sure `first_quote != second_quote` when you've iterated over the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can't modify the source string, then I think you should look at a combination of `strchr()` and `strrchr()` - at least, if you want to use library functions for everything.

- First use `strrchr()` to find the last quote.
- Then repeatedly use `strchr()` to find quotes from the front, up to the time it returns the last quote found by `strrchr()`.
- The combination of the previous result and the result of `strrchr()` gives you the quotes around the string you are interested in.

Alternatively:

- First use `strrchr()` to find the last quote.
- Write a loop to search backwards from there to find the previous quote, remembering not to search before the start of the string in the case that it is malformed and contains only one quote.

Both will work.  Depending on the balance of probabilities, it is quite possible that the loop will outperform even a highly optimized `strchr()` wrapped in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I'll end up using the alternative as you mentioned!

Comment: uber hack suggestion: do the first step as before.  set that quote to a nul, use strrchr again!, don't forget to fix the quote you broke!

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: one hopes that the data string is declared as `const char *` to discourage such abuses :D